# Virtualized environments

Tags: eclipse, virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualization

My boss wants me to create a standardized virtual development environment for our company.

This environment should consist mainly of Eclipse (Kepler) with a fairly specific plugin. He claimed Vagrant to be one of the tools we could use to achieve this goal.

Our needs are more geared towards the actual developing process instead of the process of software deployment. What Vagrant seems to be built for is emulating a developement environment  in the sense of hosting stuff like apache, and managing the specific dependencies different projects need.

Our needs are different - What my boss wants is to create a complete virtual work environment where developers connect to a remote server and find themselves in a linux GUI like KDE or Xfce. For this task, Vagrant seems to be not very well suited.

I eventually managed to get this to work with the help of Xming, Virtual Box and Vagrant. However the solution does not work very well, since the emulated work environment is running quite slowly.

My question is, is Vagrant even geared towards transferring the whole development process (including! writing the code) into the Virtual Boxes it creates, or is Vagrant geared towards local development while the Virtual Boxes take up the role of stuff like an apache webserver?

I realized this question was pretty "broad" but as I'm just getting started with virtual development environments, I felt the available documentation for Vagrant was lacking.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vagrant is a good choice: it's just a command line front-end for a VM.

Start from an Ubuntu Image, provision it to install what you need through the command line, then package it with `vagrant package`.

If you absolutely need the GUI for provisioning, add:

```
xhost +
```

your host's `.bashrc`, and you can run `eclipse` on the guest.

The people who will use your box will also need to add `xhost +` to their `.bashrc`. Or you could give them a magic script that does `xhost + && vagrant up && vagrant ssh -c eclipse`.

Comment: First of all - thank you. The point is (maybe that wasn't clear enough in the OP) that I do not only want the GUI for provisioning, I want the future users to completely work in the virtual machine. In my case, Vagrant ssh should connect to a complete virtual desktop. This is where I thought Vagrant wasn't my program of choice, because most if not all people working with vagrant mainly used it for the deployment process (aka running stuff like apache, or jenkins).

Comment: In that case, why not use Virtual Box directly (creates a GUI window inside the new system)? Just make a pre packaged box with everything they need. In that case however, I would just tell people to make a new partition on their computers, install operating system X on it, and give them a provisioning shell script. There is probably some way of automating that further. The big advantage of a virtual machine is when you want to allow people to use their own tools while developing. VMs can be much slower and generate other complications.

Comment: Quick Google search gave me this option without VMs for a Ubuntu based system: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: Thanks again. This was pretty much my line of thought as well. I consider my question answered.